Join multiple objects that all use the same material, which has a randomized input
I'm new to Blender, I created as an exercise a wall made out of bricks, each brick uses the same material with a color ramp that takes the random field of the Object Info node to achieve an effect like this :

Now I'd like to join all the bricks into a single "wall" object to then use in Unreal, but if I do that it'll lose the single brick variety. How do I join the bricks without losing the visuals I just created? Here's the material as well :

Thanks in advance!

did you try selecting all of them -> ctrl-j ?

Before you worry about joining walls, have you actually tried exporting an object into Unreal with any material created in Blender using nodes? - There are major limits to the nodes you can export from Blender! - .fbx export why there are no materials or textures.

@Chris yes, unfortunately doing that re-applies the material logic to the single object, so it's all one color

@JohnEason Yes, I hadn't read that specific thread but my plan was to bake the material into a texture and export that, and try to use it in Unreal and learn the pitfalls of it. But I'd rather bake one single texture instead of each single brick :D

Ok. Fair enough. I didn't know whether you were aware of the pitfalls.

I found a solution to the issue, partially as what was suggested here
I unwrapped all the UVs of the single object on the one single texture, making sure they all occupy their own space, baked the texture like suggested in the linked answer, then I could CTRL+J the bricks into one single object and create a simple material shader with the newly created texture. :)
